# Is it right to use the Json file as a site information and settings (Django)?

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a django project. And I want to use a *JSON* file for site information and settings (Like phone number | About Text | Contact Us information).

Like this --->

```
{
   "about_text": "Hi this is about text",
   "phone": "0912------984",
   "email": "text@text.com"
}
```

And using these in View...

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render

def about(request):
    with open("data_file.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    context = {
        "about_us_text": data['about_text']  # Using *marked* lib to render to html (In template)
    }
    return render(request, 'about.html', context)
```

- **Is it correct? Is not the solution the best? Doesn't it cause a
  problem?**
- **I think there is a better solution because it might take time and
  slow down the program... .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a better solution to get this request on the user side to receive and use the Json file?

Like This... (BACK)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', context)
```

And use this JS/jQuery script?

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/info.json', function(data) {
        var text = `${data.about_text}`;
        $(".about").html(text);
});
```

I **think** this is better because it sends the request from the user and the fetching operation is done on the user side.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know till django3.2, there is no official choice to tell which is best, json, yaml, ini, environment variable, etc.

But it should not slow down the program since django just reads the data once.